No notations from custom entries inside the proof state
In the previous question I was told to create custom notations for my formal logical system.
In order for the notation to work I had to change the symbol from the answer:
Notation "A" := (f_atom A) (A ident, in custom frm_view at level 0).

to be a custom formula, not just an atom:
Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).

Here is what I got so far:
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Parameter atom : Set.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Scope formula_scope.
Open Scope formula_scope.
Declare Custom Entry formula_view.

(* Adding notations according to priority *)
Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom formula_view at level 1, in custom formula_view at level 1).

(*
  Implication is weaker then conjunction and disjunction, but it is required
  for their definitions, that's why we introduce it's notation before them.
 *)
Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 4).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 2, at level 0).

Check fun p q => f_imp (f_imp (f_not (f_atom q)) (f_not (f_atom p))) (f_imp (f_atom p) (f_atom q)).

Definition conjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~ (A -> ~ B)$.
Notation "A /\ B" := (conjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 2, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition disjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~A -> B$.
Notation "A \/ B" := (disjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 3, in custom formula_view at level 3, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition equivalence (A B: formula) : formula := $(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)$.
Notation "A <-> B" := (equivalence A B) (B custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 5, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 77) : formula_scope.

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) A := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 78, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 79) : formula_scope.

(* We now come to main definitions. We first define a type
   Γ |- A whose elements are derivations of formula A
   from assumptions Γ. These are presented as derivation trees,
   rather than more traditional lists.

   Note the difference between declaring that Γ |- A
   is a Prop vs. a Type:

   - if Γ |- A is a Prop, then it is expresses *provability*
   - if Γ |- A is a Type, then it expresses *proof derivations*

   The practical difference is this: if Γ |- A is a Type, then
   its element is a derivation tree which can be freely inspected
   and used; but if Γ |- A is a Prop, then its elements are
   (abstract) witnesses of provability that can only be expected
   for the purpose of constructing an element of Prop.
 *)
Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98).
Inductive entails (Γ : formula -> Prop) : formula -> Type :=
  | hypo : forall A, A ∈ Γ -> Γ |- A (* every hypothesis is provable *)
  | axiom1 : forall A B , Γ |- $A -> B -> A$
  | axiom2 : forall A B C, Γ |- $(A -> B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C)$
  | axiom3 : forall A B, Γ |- $(~ B -> ~ A) -> (~ B -> A) -> B$
  | mp : forall A B, Γ |- B -> Γ |- $B -> A$ -> Γ |- A (* modus ponens *)
where "Γ |- A" := (entails Γ A).

(* It is convenient to make some parameters implicit. *)
Arguments hypo {_} {_} _.
Arguments axiom1 {_} _ _.
Arguments axiom2 {_} _ _ _.
Arguments axiom3 {_} _ _.
Arguments mp {_} {_} (_).

(* Here are some basic observation about |-. *)

Lemma imply_self Γ A : Γ |- $A -> A$.
Proof.
  apply mp with (B := $A -> A -> A$). (* We stand here *)
  - exact (axiom1 A A).
  - apply mp with (B := $A -> (A -> A) -> A$).
    + exact (axiom1 A $A -> A$).
    + exact (axiom2 A $A -> A$ A).
Qed.


Unfortunately, pretty printing of notations is gone when proving the theorems. Standing in the theorem imply_self will give us the following:
2 goals (ID 35)
  
  Γ : formula -> Prop
  A : formula
  ============================
  Γ |- f_imp A (f_imp A A)

goal 2 (ID 36) is:
 Γ |- f_imp (f_imp A (f_imp A A)) (f_imp A A)

So, coq can understand the notation inside the source code, but it doesn't use it when printing the state of the proof.
How to fix this?

(* ... *)
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 0).
(* ... *)
Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 4, at level 0).
(* ... *)

The start level must be $4$. Since $2 < 4$, the printer does not print $\to$.


At level 4 or at level 5? The lowest is equivalence with level 5. As far as i understand the levels of p in "( p )" and "'$' p '$'" must be equal to the level of the lowest level connective?

@user4035 Oh, then it must be $5$.
